# Integrate OOPath Syntax in a drools like rule, using Xtext

Tags: java, drools, code-generation, xtext

I try to implement oopath syntax in a drools like rule, but I have some issues regarding the non variables oopaths. For example, here is what I try to generate in the when block:

```
when $rt : string(Variables 
                  $yr1t : /path1/F
                  $yr2t : /path2/F
                  $yr3t : path3.path4/PATH5
                  $yr4t : path3
                  $yr5t : /path3
                  Conditions
                  $yr4t == $yr5t + 3
                  $yr3t != $yr2t

                  //FROM HERE IS THE PROBLEM:

                  $yr3t == p/path/f    
                  $yr3t == /g/t
                 /path2/F[g==$yr1t]
                  )
```

The problem I am facing is that my grammar doesn't support this format and I don't know how to modify the existing one in order to support even the last 3 statements.
Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Model:
    declarations+=Declaration*
;

Temp:
 elementType=ElementType 
 ;
ElementType:
 typeName=('string'|'int'|'boolean');

Declaration:
    Rule
;

@Override
terminal ID: ('^'|'$')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;
terminal PATH: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9')*;

Rule:
    'Filter'
    'rule' ruleDescription=STRING
    '@specification' QualifiedNameSpecification
    'ruleflow-group' ruleflowDescription=STRING
    'when' (name += ID ':' atribute += Temp '(' 'Variables'?
                                            //(varName += ID ':' QualifiedNameVariabilePath)*
                                            (variablesList += Variable)*
                                            'Conditions'?
                                            
                                            (exp += EvalExpression)*
                                            
                                            ')'
           )*
;

QualifiedNameSpecification:  '(' STRING ')';
QualifiedNameVariabilePath: (('/'|'.')? PATH)* ;


ExpressionsModel:
 elements += AbstractElement*;
AbstractElement:
 Variable | EvalExpression ;
Variable:
 //'var'
  name=ID ':' QualifiedNameVariabilePath; //expression=Expression;
EvalExpression:
 //'eval'
  expression=Expression;
Expression: Or;
Or returns Expression:
     And ({Or.left=current} "||" right=And)*
;
And returns Expression:
 Equality ({And.left=current} "&&" right=Equality)*
;
Equality returns Expression:
 Comparison (
 {Equality.left=current} op=("=="|"!=")
 right=Comparison
 )*
;
Comparison returns Expression:
 PlusOrMinus (
 {Comparison.left=current} op=(">="|"<="|">"|"<")
 right=PlusOrMinus
 )*
;
PlusOrMinus returns Expression:
 MulOrDiv (
 ({Plus.left=current} '+' | {Minus.left=current} '-')
 right=MulOrDiv
 )*
;
MulOrDiv returns Expression:
 Primary (
 {MulOrDiv.left=current} op=('*'|'/')
 right=Primary
 )*
;
Primary returns Expression:
 '(' Expression ')' |
 {Not} "!" expression=Primary |
 Atomic
;
Atomic returns Expression:
 {IntConstant} value=INT |
 {StringConstant} value=STRING |
 {BoolConstant} value=('true'|'false') |
 {VariableRef} variable=[Variable]
;
```

EDIT: To make it more clear, the question is how do I modify my grammar in order to support oopath syntax without binding them to a variable, something like a temporary object.